# react-native iOS app not showing static/local assets (images) after deploying

Tags: ios, deployment, react-native

I have all my static images in a folder called "images" in the root of my project. However, after I run the following command to bundle my app, the app works but no image is shown.

The command I use to bundle:

```
./react-native bundle --minify --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./assets
```

Note that the assets folder is created and it has my images folder with all images ok.

Can you help please?

Comment: Could you give more details please. Simulator or device? If device, how did you deploy it? And can you please post a code sample of one of your image usages.

Comment: It happens on both device and simulator.

Comment: What I did to deploy it: 1) edited the schema to set the "release" mode. 2) changed the bundle location to use the local main bundle (main.jsbundle) 3) Executed the command above to bundle the app. 4) Selected my device and ran it.

Comment: Example usage of images: <Image  source={require('./images/comments.png')} />

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The asset destination and the main.jsbundle have to be in the same folder. Try:

```
./react-native bundle --minify --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ./release/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./release
```

The bundler will create an assets folder in there anyway.

**UPDATE** including information from the discussions below:

The react-native-xcode.sh script that is executed in a XCode build step copies the main.jsbundle and the assets folder created by the bundler into the app package. If you want to deploy the package manually you need to make sure, that those files are copied. The easiest way is to include the main.jsbundle directly into the project and create a folder link to the assets folder. Verify that both are showing up in  'Build Phases' -> 'Copy Bundle Resources'.

Comment: What should be the jsCodeLocation path in this case? The current value is: jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];

Comment: probably jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"release/main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"]; You can also try do --bundle-output ./main.jsbundle --assets-dest .  The point is, that require() searches the assets relative to the current main.jsbundl

Comment: Sorry didn't work. I think the problem is that the bundle always creates a folder called "assets" and copies the "images" folder inside it.

Comment: But this is the expected behavior. The bundle has to be next to the asset folder. Both need to be copied to the device/simulator, as well. I'm not sure how the default schemes handle this, because I made my own. I integrated the assets folder as folder link in xcode and made sure it gets copied in 'Build Phases' -> 'Copy Bundle Resources'

Comment: Ok finally got it working. You were right as both assets folder and the main.jsbundle have to be inside the same folder. However,  things worked when I put both of them in the same directory where the default Images.xcassets is. Also  I selected "create folder references" on adding the assets folder and the main.jsbundle to the project. This way, they both appeared in   'Build Phases' -> 'Copy Bundle Resources'  and all worked as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Yep this did the trick for me. I was missing adding the generated assets folder (not the individual files) in the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase.

Comment: I have added same, images are added in bundle resources. still images are not loading. I can see the added images and main,jsbundle in resources.

Comment: @Afsara is totally right, images are still not loading, despite of the assets folder inside my iOS project.

Comment: @YuriiN.  Did you get the solution? Please help me if you know the answer. I am struggling with this issues since last week. :(

Comment: @SagarTrehan unfortunately not at all, but I remember that problem was with Fastlane, so maybe you should dig in that way.

Comment: these commands worked for me as an npm run build script `npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --dev false --assets-dest ./rn-assets --reset-cache --bundle-output ./main.jsbundle && mv ./main.jsbundle ./rn-assets` and in your controller/Delegate reference 'rn-assets/main'  also be sure to add rn-assets with folder references to xcode

Answer (score 68):

Please check XCode console log first. You will find that the app couldn't find out those specific image assets on path "{project name}.app/assets/resources/.."

[image]

So, you need to put images on those fixed paths, unlike iOS native App.  Lets add "assets" folder to your 'Copy Bundle Resources'.

**Step 1:**
Select XCode project -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources

**Step 2**
[image]

**Step 3**
[image]

**Step 4**
[image]

Comment: Hi @SagarTrehan, I hope you go through the steps and execute accordingly. Do you see any problem while executing?

Comment: Hi @Milan, I followed exact same steps multiple time, but still I am facing same issue that images are not getting loaded in iOS build. I am using react-native version "0.59.10" can this issue related to latest react-native?

Comment: @SagarTrehan, let me check and get back

Comment: Hi @SagarTrehan, I tested with react-native 0.60.3, it works perfectly. I will ask to check *Step 4* carefully. There you need to set "Create folder references". Please check that.

Comment: If this is still not working, please share error log @SagarTrehan

Comment: Its working for me now. I was copying the "$Project/src/assets" folder in "Copy Bundle Resources", instead of "$Project/ios/assets". This is stupid mistake from me. Very thankful to you for providing the solution.

Comment: Hey @SagarTrehan, good to hear that it worked for you. please vote if this answer works for you.

Comment: it worked for me just as you said, just selecting the assets folder inside the ios folder and then adding it to the copy bundle ressource.

Comment: @BloodyMonkey, could you please tell if you get any error while executing the first command?

Comment: @MilanKamilya No errors, assets seems to be successfully copied but i still have " [framework] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)' " in xcode terminal for each assets when building

Comment: Cool... actual solution! Wish this was like automatic or something... just don't understand why the discontinuity here lol

Comment: I tried all the above steps but the app started crashing in release mode.

Answer (score 24):

For a newer version of react-native use the following:

```
react-native bundle --minify --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios
```

You will see `asset` folder and `main.jsbundle` file in the `ios` folder. After that go to `Xcode` -> `build phases` -> `copy bundle resources` and then add the `asset` folder and `main.jsbundle` file. Don't forget to click on the `Copy if needed`

Comment: which version of react-native are you using? this command was working for v0.55, if I remember the version correctly

Comment: Still works with v0.62.2. Tnx for the help man, the issue was getting really annoying for me!

Comment: This solution helped me

Answer (score 12):

Local assets do not load even if you are working on a `newer Xcode versions` i.e. `12.x` or later. There are two solutions to it :

1. Upgrade react-native versions
2. Or go to below file:

```
node_modules > react-native > Libraries > Images > RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m search for `if (_currentFrame)`
```

add the following else block to the if block as below

```
if (_currentFrame) {
  layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
  layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
 } else {
  [super displayLayer:layer];
 }
```

If its older xcode you need to add `assets` and `main.jsbundle` under `Xcode -> build phases -> copy bundle resources`

or

Use library `react-native-image-fix` [Here's the link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fix-image) try the below commands:

```
npm install --save react-native-fix-image
npx react-native-fix-image

Rebuild the project.
```

Answer (score 6):

for me the solution was to run the command to build assets:

```
npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

Answer (score 2):

- Create an `Assets` folder inside the `ios` directory.

[image: create Assets in iOS folder]

- Add this folder to your project.
- Select the `Create groups` option.

[image: add to project]

- `Assets` folder won't show up in `Copy Bundle Resources` like it does in other solutions.
  [image: copy bundle resources]
- It will show up in `Project Navigator`. It looks different from the `AWS` folder because `AWS` is added as `Create folder references`
  [image: project navigator]

**Tested on**

- `react-native` version `> 0.63`.
- `Xcode 12 and above`.

**Note**

- Solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513935/1206052) I didn't want to use any command/script to force it as bundling comes out of the box.
- Solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49457267/1206052) This solution didn't work for me.

Comment: but how the real static images are copied/linked from the original <root>/assets folder into the <root>/ios/Assets one ?

Comment: @Jonathan. I think the script for copying resources to some new place inside the compiled file is already there in the `build scripts`. For Android, it works seamlessly but for iOS, it fails in the absence of a destination directory. When I analyzed the apk I found all the images referred inside the project as `require('../../assets/images/ic_abc.png'),` were copied to `res` inside the compiled apk. How I came to know about creating an Assets folder for iOS was purely a result of a comparison with my old project.

Comment: DeltaCap019 thanks for the answer, I later realised what caused the issue. The expo-update package, was pointing the asset location to a network location. Removing it, solved the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue with the NX monorepo. This answer fixed the assets linking.

Answer (score 2):

All the above questions are working.

But watch out, in my case i had to make this in this order :

1. delete the old assets folder first (in `ios/assets`)
2. add this in my `package.json` under the `scripts` attributes (so i can run it later, or for other developers)

```json
"build:ios": "npx react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='ios'"
```

3. Go to my Xcode (i am on v14.0.1), the to the "build phase" tab, and add my "assets" folder previoulsy created.
4. delete my app in my simulator
5. clean build iOS (Product > clean build)
6. run `npm run build:ios` in the root of my project

Answer (score -7):

I fixed that problem changing my xcode version from `9.3`  to `9.2`