# Blank images in deployed iOS React Native application

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, build

I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354998/react-native-ios-app-not-showing-static-assets-images-after-deploying/49457267#49457267) and nothing helps.

So, I have such structure:

- src

  - components

    - (my components, buttons e.g.)

      - images

        - ...
      - component.tsx

where every component has its own folder with images.

Command for building iOS:

```
node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
```

I'm also using [rnpm](https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm) with such config:

```
"rnpm": {
  "assets": [
    "assets/images"
  ]
}
```

The problem is simple - production build of my iOS application doesn't have images at all. But `TouchableOpacity` on them works correctly.

Android production build works fine, everything is OK.

So, how can we build iOS application with images?

Comment: Why do you specifie in your rnpm config that your assets are in `assets/images`, while your assets are in `src/components/{component}/images`?

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp Good question, I have also `assets/images` folders in root, but images from that folder are also blank.

Comment: Can you show how you import your images ?

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp Sure, `<Image
              style={{
                width: 30,
                height: 30
              }}
              source={require('./images/myImage.png')}
            />` something like that. And I also edited the question, to show how `images` folder and component are correlating.

Comment: Same for me. I have bundled everything properly and done everything right in Xcode yet now success.

Comment: @JeremyF, for me, problem disappeared when stopped using [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools), but that's really not an answer.

Comment: @YuriiN. Just solved it. I changed my bundle command assets-dest to ./ instead of ./ios or ./assets and that did the trick.

Comment: @JeremyF yep, I did it too, unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem for me. So, it depends.