# react-native IOS app not showing assets in simulator

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to run a react-native app in Xcode simulator, But the app not showing assets(images) so I tried this:
XCode project -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources, then adding assets to my Copy Bundle Resources. 
When I do this the app turns to blank white page,this issue is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354998/react-native-ios-app-not-showing-static-assets-images-after-deploying) I want to know why this solution didn't work for me? and what can I do to solve it?
note: i can see images in android simulator

Comment: What do you mean he doesn't show his assets? Show me the code.

Comment: i mean i can't see images in IOS, but it's works perfectly in Android. looks like react-native can't read images from src folder (just in IOS) when i run it in android emulator i can see images...

Answer (score 0):

For images included via Xcode asset catalogs or in the Android drawable folder, use the image name without the extension:

```js
<Image source={{ uri: 'app_icon' }} style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }} />
```

For images in the Android assets folder, use the `asset:/` scheme:

```js
<Image source={{ uri: 'asset:/app_icon.png' }} style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }} />
```

Comment: I checked it, but seems this isn't my issue,
I think I have the same case in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354998/react-native-ios-app-not-showing-static-assets-images-after-deploying
but none of the answers works for me

Comment: @KamalCherkaoui If you are saving it to the Relative Native Image folder, you can use it without saving it to the set of Xcode .