# Loading local image in react native 0.60.3 and Xcode 11

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, xcode11

Edited: only don't work in release

I use react native version 0.60.3. Before one year make an application with local images and it works well. I update Xcode to version 11 and old code and images work well also. I try to add new images for dark mode but the image doesn't show, there isn't an error, only blank space. 
In code use images from js file like :
`"url":require("../images/page1.png")`.

Images are added to copy bundle resources.

I try with command :
`npx react-native bundle --entry-file='index.ios.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios`

and copy assets and main.jsbundle to Xcode and get the same results, before I don't have assets folder in XCode, images are been in copy bundle resources.
Old images work (which are added before one year), new images don't work. Did I miss something? I don't have an error and don't know how to fix this issue.

My code:

```
   <CustomImage 
        width={getImgWidth} height={getImgHeight} 
        lightpath={it.url} 
        darkpath={it.urldark}
        darkmode={theme.darkmode} />
```

CustomImage.js

```
const CustomImage = (props) => {
  return (
   <View style={{ width: props.width, height: props.height }}>
  {props.darkmode ? (
    <Image
      resizeMode="contain"
      style={{ width: props.width, height: props.height }}
      source={props.darkpath}
    />
     ) : (
    <Image
      resizeMode="contain"
      style={{ width: props.width, height: props.height }}
      source={props.lightpath}
    />
  )}
  </View>
 );
 };
```

Comment: can you post the example of the code

Comment: if it's an Image element do: `<Image source={require("../images/page1.png")} />`

Comment: I edit the question and add my code.

Comment: this work  <Image style={{ width: props.width, height: props.height } source={require("../imagesdark/page1.png")} />, dont work when use from "url":require("../imagesdark/page1.png"),  light images works well.

Comment: Did the below answer work?

Comment: work in debug, don't work in release

Answer (score 0):

Since `props.darkpath = require("../images/page1.png")`
Could you try:

```js
<Image
      resizeMode="contain"
      style={{ width: props.width, height: props.height }}
      source={`${props.darkpath}`}
    />
```

Comment: I have required in darkpath "url":require("../images/page1.png")

Comment: Do you mean `props.darkpath = require("../images/page1.png")` ?

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35366243/11380693