# Images not showing in react native application in release mode

Tags: ios, react-native

React native application is working absolutely fine in debug mode but running in release mode image are not visible. I am using react-native@0.62.2.

I tried some solution from [react-native iOS app not showing static assets (images) after deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354998/react-native-ios-app-not-showing-static-assets-images-after-deploying)
but still not working.

I get this in xcode console

[image]

EDIT:
Found out that the error is because of a package "react-native-webview-quilljs". Installing it doesn't create problem but when importing it. After import app will run but editor will not render as well as all the images are not rendering.

Comment: Are you confirming the issue is coming from react-native-webview-quilljs? Just to double confirm if you remove `react-native-webview-quilljs` from project, your image assets is able to render on iOS?

Comment: yes, installing the package is not a problem but when i import the package even if i dont use it, it gives this problem, but I want editor too

Comment: I mean, have you tried not using the package to ensure your project works as expected? If its a package issue, raise issue to the their github / do a PR / change lib.

Comment: yes, application is working fine without the package. thanks for the suggestion. I have raised an issue in their github

Answer (score 0):

This thread solved the issue for me: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279#issuecomment-658244428

You can find that file in your node_modules folder. It seems like there was an issue with the Image module and they didn't fix it until the most recent version of React Native at the time of posting. Hope it works for you. Maybe someone who understands it more can elaborate on why exactly it solves the issue.

Comment: this didn't fix for me

Comment: I checked this condition already added in my library but still images are not showing to me