# Local images now displaying React Native

Tags: react-native

My local images have suddenly stopped displaying in my app.

I tried the solution proposed here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354998/react-native-ios-app-not-showing-static-assets-images-after-deploying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11STL.png)
but it didn't work.

[image: This is the structure of my app]

I'm importing my image as follows:

```
import image from '../../assets/images/home-1.jpg';
...
return (
      <SafeAreaView style={[styles.container, {margin: 0}]}>
        <Image source={image} style={styles.image} />
        ...
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
...
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
image: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
  },
...
```

But my image looks like this:
[image]

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your used is wrong.
You can try:

```
 <Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />
```

More in docs of [React-native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images). Please follow it.

Comment: Nope, I tried using `const image = require('../../assets/images/home-1.jpg');` but it still doesn't work. The weird thing is that it used to work.