# React Native BareWorkflow images don't show when ios release build

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Environment:

xCode 12

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1 

react-native: 0.63.4
```

Hi! I'm trying release build with react native bare workflow. Debug build was no problem, But after implementing release build, my app doesn't show any images form assets directory.

Xcode log is like this.

> > [native] Could not find image
> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/610F6543-2E6A-404E-8D54-6506084093DE/Library/Application%20Support/.expo-internal/assets/assets/icon_password.png

I tried ways below URl, but I coudn't solove the problem after all.

[react-native iOS app not showing static assets (images) after deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354998/react-native-ios-app-not-showing-static-assets-images-after-deploying)

Please give me your knowlege...:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem too.

My steps to solve the problem were:

1. execute `react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios`

This command, among other things, creates main.jsbundle file and assets folder in ios directory

2. Add "main.jsbundle" and "assets" folder to 'Copy Bundle Resources'.
3. Rebuild project.

p.s This post helped me a lot https://stackoverflow.com/a/35366243

Hope these steps help you!